# CNAME + PointDNS + HEROKU not working properly

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, dns

recently I added PointNDS to my project on Heroku and I can access to the web via myapp.com, but if you try 'www.myapp.com', i got the message: "There is no such app on that directory" or something like that

I added the url as suggested ond the docs (myapp.com) in heroku, and also in pointdns, generating all the proper dns, cname, a, etc.

In heroku i have this domains: myapp.herokuapp.com - myapp.com

The ALIAS point to myapp.com
The CNAME point to www.myapp.com

Any idea what i have missed on the config?

Regards, and sorry if my english is not perfect, i'm still studying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each external DNS hostname needs to be registered with Heroku:

- myapp.com `ALIAS` => myapp.herokuapp.com
- www.myapp.com `CNAME` => myapp.herokuapp.com

Both `myapp.com` and `www.myapp.com` need to be registered as domains on your Heroku app.